# Calculate the number of pages required form expanding report design into multip pages

Tags: real-analysis

I am programmer, I am writing a report designer and the problem is
report contains five section
1 - Report Header visible in the first page only
2 - Page Header visible in all pages
3 - Details Section visible in all pages
4 - Page Footer visible in all pages
5 - Report Footer visible in last page only

- givens:
  1 - Page size is known
  2 - Each section size is known
  3 - the number of data rows to be expanded in the details section is known
  4 - each row height in the details section is known
- required:
  How many number of pages required to output a report given the previous parameters,
  I need an equation, or mathematical model to govern the rules of this thing

Comment: even you can tell me the field of science I should read about it

Answer (score 1):

In real life one usually faces additional problems such as detail rows of different height, intermediate headings requiring layout decisions, or orphan/widow avoidance such that *simulating* the whole process in a first run is not one of the worst ideas.

But apart from this, we can say the follwing:
Let $p$ be the page size, $h_0$ exceptional first page header size, $h$ generic header size, $f$ generig footer size, $f_0$ exceptional last page footer size, $r$ detail row height, $n$ detail row count. (I assume here that the generic header does not appear on the first page and the generic footer does not appear on the last page; in other words, if these assumptions are not correct, then $h_0$ and $f_0$ are to be understood as *including* the generic header/footer).

The page fits on one page if $$nr+h_0+f_0\le p.$$
Otherwise, we can fit $m_0:=\left\lfloor\frac{p-h_0-f}{r}\right\rfloor$ rows on the first, $m_1:=\left\lfloor\frac{p-h-f_0}{r}\right\rfloor$ on the last and $m:=\left\lfloor\frac{p-h-f}{r}\right\rfloor$ on any intermediate page.
Thus $k$ pages suffice if 
$$ m_0+m_1+(k-2)m\ge n.$$
Therefore, we find the needed number $k$ of pages as
$$k=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }nr+h_0+f_0\le p,\\\left\lceil\tfrac{n-m_0-m_1}{m}\right\rceil+2&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases} $$